# Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86_64,i386 (IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework) +IONIC 2 + IBM MFP 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic2, app-store, mobilefirst-cli

[image]

> I'm getting these error when upload to appstore.
>
> **I had added the IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework in Targets => General => Embedded Binaries.** (By default it is there in Linked Framework and Libraries)
>
> **If I remove IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework from Embedded Libraries (By default it is there in Linked Framework and Libraries), Build will success, but App will crash.**

**I had tried http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/**
Please see the screen, is it correct?[image]

> I could take adhoc build,
>
> I'm using Ionic version 2 and IBM MFP 8.0. and
>
> cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017060910 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"

Please help me to solve this
Thanks

Comment: Please let us know what version of cordova-plugin-mfp you are using.  Also, did you build the cordova app and then open the produced xcodeproj in Xcode?  I'm not aware of special steps that you should have to take like you're describing above.

Comment: Dear John, I'm using 
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017060910 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation".

And I open this project using Xcodeproject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue while using another framework ("Intercom"). I was also adding it in embedded binaries and the run script to select the correct architecture. The solution that worked for me is -

- Remove the corresponding framework and run-scripts that are creating the problem. Then compile and run the code.
- Add the embedded framework first and then add the run-script. Please make sure the order in the build phases should be like the embedded framework above the run script which you use to select the correct architecture.

This worked for m, I hope this will help you too.